# mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'list' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, mysql, list, mysql-error-1064

## question answered

I am attempting to insert a value into my table where it selects an ID by matching it with its name and inserting it into a second table. However when I print out the selected value it prints [(1,)] which is classed as a list. So when it tries to insert the value into a table I receive the error that im trying to insert a list when I just want the value 1.

the code for it is in python and its shown below:

```
 def createaudit():
    sitename2_info = sitename.get()
    print(sitename2_info, "testing2")
    name2_info = name2.get()
    print(name2_info)
    name3_info = name3.get()
    print(name3_info)
    # Sql code for writing the data that was written in the regsitering page. 
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
    # the site query matches the inputted username with the corresponding userID and inserts the userID into userID_fk
    siteIDQuery = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
    cursor.execute(siteIDQuery, [sitename2_info])
    siteID_fetch = cursor.fetchall()
    print(siteID_fetch)
    sitequery = "INSERT INTO `audit`(`siteID_fk`, `auditor1`, `auditor2`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    sitequery_vals = (siteID_fetch, name2_info, name3_info)
    cursor.execute(sitequery, sitequery_vals)
    # prints how many rows were inserted to make sure values are put into the database
    print(cursor.rowcount)
    cnn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    cnn.close()
```

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the value?  Something like `siteID_fetch[0][0]`?

Comment: I did siteID_fetch[0] which didn't work however I tried yours and it worked. Thanks

Comment: siteID_fetch[0] would return a tuple (1,), so you need to get the first element from that tuple, hence the additional [0].  Glad it worked.